# Is fb_graph or Koala ruby gem better than facebooker2, using the facebook graph?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebooker

Is the [fb_graph](http://github.com/nsanta/fbgraph) gem better?

It seems to be newer, but the [facebooker](http://github.com/mmangino/facebooker) has a lot more people using.

http://github.com/nsanta/fbgraph

http://github.com/mmangino/facebooker

Update:

I looked into koala, and it seems it is a good choice as well.

http://github.com/arsduo/koala

I also figure out that fb_graph is different than fbgraph. This is the right one:

http://github.com/nov/fb_graph

And there is a new facebooker, that uses that Open Graph API, but it doesnt look as mature as the others:

http://github.com/wallace/facebooker2

Comment: I looked into koala, and it seems it is a good choice as well.
http://github.com/arsduo/koala


http://github.com/wallace/facebooker2

Comment: The facebooker2 link you posted is actually a fork.  The true project link can be found here:
https://github.com/mmangino/facebooker2

Comment: See a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928040/which-facebook-ruby-api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using Koala. It seems to be the best choice now. Facebooker2 is still very early stage, and Koala does a great job wrapping everything.

Don't get confused! Facebooker is for the old FB API!

Comment: You would have wanted Mogli, not Facebooker2

Answer (score 10):

I've been using Koala and have been very happy.  It's very low level - meaning no abstractions that try to do stuff for you.  The graph API is very straightforward, so this the best approach.

Answer (score 2):

The original Facebooker gem was split into two pieces for the new api - [Facebooker2](https://github.com/mmangino/facebooker2) for front-end helpers/auth and [Mogli](https://github.com/mmangino/mogli) for back-end open graph api calls.  Both are managed by the same person who did the original Facebooker gem - mike mangino - who does a great job of supporting both.  Mogli is most directly comparable to Koala.

Answer (score 0):

So far, I'm a big fan of koala, but I've not tried fb_graph. I did post a comparison of a few facebook gems here: http://jeffdeville.com/minifb-vs-koala-vs-mogli-facebook-graph-api-r