# Rails 3 and Facebook share

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, oauth

in my app I want to have the "Share" Facebook thing in the items with a pre-defined message, so the user clicks in "Share" and gets redirected to the Allow/Deny page and after allowing, the pre-defined message is automatically posted in the user's facebook wall. What's the best gem for my problem(I am sure there is one :p)?

Thanks!

P.S: I looked at the facebooker gem but it seems out-of-date and I have to use the latest Rails 3.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at some related questions. [Is fb_graph or Koala gem better than facebooker2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928262/is-fb-graph-or-koala-gem-better-than-facebooker2) and [Which Facebook Ruby API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928040/which-facebook-ruby-api)

I'm currently using a custom solution for our facebook integration but I have been looking moving to a gem and these seem to be the main choices:

1. [koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala)
2. [fb_graph](https://github.com/nsanta/fbgraph)
3. [facebooker2](https://github.com/mmangino/facebooker2)

So far I agree with David from the "Which Facebook Ruby API" post and am leaning towards fb_graph because of its simplicity.  It should handle your requirements without any problems, just take a look at the [sample app](http://fbgraphsample.heroku.com/).

Answer (score 3):

koala seems to a better choice, as the remaining gems are outdated. Either they support the old facebook API or are not in active development.

I am successfully using koala with rails 3.

https://github.com/arsduo/koala