# So many Facebook libraries for Ruby, which to choose?

Tags: ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So far I've come across the following Facebook API libraries for Ruby/Ruby-on-Rails:

- Facebooker
- Koala
- Mogli
- Facebooker2
- fb_graph
- facebook_oauth

I was wondering if anyone knows why there are so many, and if anyone has a rough idea of which to use when?

Answer (score 1):

I did the same search recently and ultimately chose Koala.  Facebooker was the clear choice a couple years ago, but it's out of date now with so many recent facebook api changes.  Koala and fb_graph seem to be the most popular now.  Koala is easy to use for accessing the graph api.  I haven't used it for the older rest api, though Koala does support it.  The only difficult part I've found is the facebook authentication with oauth - though that's probably facebook itself rather than Koala.

Relevant discussion here as well: [Is fb_graph or Koala ruby gem better than facebooker2, using the facebook graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928262/is-fb-graph-or-koala-gem-better-than-facebooker2)

Comment: I'm stuck on the same part as you Chris, the Oauth authentication part, but I've decided to go with Koala just because it seems to have the most documentation and discussions out there.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem : "which one to use ?" and i tried Facebooker, Mogli and fb_graph.
I can say that fb_graph is the best and the most mature and up to date and well documented ( you can read the facebook DOC and apply it to fb_graph. it works like magic).

Comment: Thanks for your input. Can I ask why you didn't try Koala? It seems to be the 2nd most "popular" option after Facebooker, but most of the Facebooker articles around the web are 1-2 years old. I'm definitely going to give fb_graph a good look.